# Ajeitando labels fora do gráfico em barras pequenas no ggplot

Tags: r, gráfico, label, barplot

Estou fazendo gráficos para descrever as respostas de um survey e gostaria de dispor a % de cada resposta. No entanto, nas respostas com baixo número, o label acaba ficando para fora do gráfico.
Preferencialmente gostaria de manter nesse estilo, com os labels em preto do lado de fora no caso de barras pequenas.

```
gráfico <- ggplot(data=filter(df,Mês=="2021-09-01" | Mês=="2021-08-01", renda != 0),
   aes(x=Classe, y=renda, group=Mês, fill=month(Mês, label=T)))+
geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(reverse=TRUE), stat="identity", width= 0.8)+
scale_color_manual(values=c("#132F3C", "#F5A700"))+
geom_text(aes(label=paste(round(renda*100,1), "%", sep="")), color="white", hjust=1.25, 
vjust=0.5, size =15, position = position_dodge2(width= 0.8, reverse=TRUE))+
coord_flip(clip="off")+
ylab("")+
xlab("")+
labs(caption = paste("...")) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#132F3C","#F5A700"),name ="")+
theme_minimal()+
theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
     axis.text.x = element_blank(),
     legend.position = "bottom",
     legend.key.width  = unit(1, "cm"),
     legend.title = element_blank(),
     legend.text = element_text(size=40),
     plot.caption = element_text(family = "Didact Gothic",hjust = 1.25,colour="grey30", size= 
28),
     text = element_text(family = "Didact Gothic", color = "grey20",size = 40))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade de fazer é criar variáveis auxiliares que corrijam a posição dado um valor arbitrário, segue um exemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Dados de exemplo

df <-
mtcars %>% 
  count(gear = as.factor(gear),vs = as.factor(vs)) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  mutate(
    p = 100*n/sum(n),
    lbl = paste(round(p,1), "%", sep="")
    ) 


#Gráfico

df %>% 
  #Variáveis auxiliares
  mutate(
    #Indicador de valor < 20
    aux = if_else(p < 20, TRUE, FALSE),
    #Auxiliar para correção da posição
    pos = if_else(p < 20, p + 12, p)
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = p,y = gear))+
  geom_col(aes(fill = vs),
           position = position_dodge())+
  #Adição de valores auxiliares
  geom_text(aes(label= lbl, x = pos, col = aux),
            hjust=1.25, 
            vjust=0.5,
            size =5,
            #Remoção da legenda
            show.legend = FALSE,
            position = position_dodge2(width= 0.8, reverse=TRUE))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("white","black"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso além da posição também modifiquei a cor do texto, para valores cujo percentual fossem inferiores a 20%.